# Swagger integration with scala and play 2.7 framework and sbt 1.5

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, sbt, swagger

I am trying to integrate swagger with my sbt scala project

I am using

Sbt - 1.5.1
Play - 2.7.3
Scala - 2.13

I am getting the following error

```
 not found: https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/iheart/play-swagger_2.13/0.10.4/play-swagger_2.13-0.10.4.pom
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.unresolvedWarningOrThrow(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:258)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.$anonfun$update$38(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at scala.util.Either$LeftProjection.map(Either.scala:573)
[error]     at lmcoursier.CoursierDependencyResolution.update(CoursierDependencyResolution.scala:227)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:60)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:59)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:133)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:73)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$20(LibraryManagement.scala:146)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:228)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:146)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:127)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChangedW$1(Tracked.scala:219)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:160)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask0$1(Defaults.scala:3667)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:49)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:62)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(Transform.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:23)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:291)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:282)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:265)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:64)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
[error]     at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
[error]     at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

Tried multiple versions of swagger. Any suggestions?

Comment: Bintray has been shut down: https://jfrog.com/blog/into-the-sunset-bintray-jcenter-gocenter-and-chartcenter/.

Comment: That's not the issue here. Bintray is still available for downloading old artifacts. _We listened to the community and will keep JCenter as a read-only repository indefinitely._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check available versions on Maven central at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.iheart/play-swagger

You'll see that there is no version published for Play 2.7 and Scala 2.13.

You may want to open an issue on the GitHub of this project to ask for such a release.

Comment: Which swagger version should I try to integrate, any suggestions?
I cant change the sbt , scala or play version